# Java equivalent of a curl cookie statement

Tags: java

I am trying to translate a curl query to POST a cookie to a URL.

The CURL query is as follows :

```
curl -v -i --cookie-jar "./cookie.txt" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{\"username\":\"acd\",\"password\":\"pwd\",\"isPasswordEncrypted\":\"false\"}"
```

The URL being :

```
http://egurl/app/app1/session/login
```

This is working perfectly in POST MAN.

But when I tried using the below statements in JAVA for the POST cookie to work :

```
URL url = new URL("http://egurl/app/app1/session/login");

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setDoOutput(true);

con.setRequestMethod("POST");

con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "{\"username\":\"acd\",\"password\":\"pwd\",\"isPasswordEncrypted\":\"false\"}");

con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

con.connect();

System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
```

Every time I try to print the response code i get a 500 server error.

I am pretty novice at POST,Get and Cookies in JAVA. Can I get some help?

Comment: The manual for `curl` says that `-d` is used to pass data to the request. You're passing it as a property (named "Cookie", for some reason) instead.

Comment: So i need to have this cookie created which has the username and pwd and posted on the URL. The Jsession ID for the same cookie will be used for other Get and PUT request to different URL which uses the same session. how do pass data as a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise a different approach. Instead of coding the HTTP request on your own, I would suggest using a third party library that does it for you. Well known libraries are [Apache HTTP Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga) and [OK Http Client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/). However, there is by far less known but much simpler Http Client in Open Source MgntUtils library (written by me). Your code may look something like this

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
client.setConnectionUrl("http://egurl/app/app1/session/login");
client.sendHttpRequest(HttpMethod.POST, "{\"username\":\"acd\",\"password\":\"pwd\",\"isPasswordEncrypted\":\"false\"}");
```

Here is the link to [JavaDoc for the HttpClient](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). The MgntUtils library could be found as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (with source code and Javadoc)

BTW, it appears that in your curl you don't set Request property "Cookie" but just send your String `{\"username\":\"acd\",\"password\":\"pwd\",\"isPasswordEncrypted\":\"false\"}"` to the server as body of your request. That is what my sample code does. If you need to set a request property there is a method for this as well

```
public void setRequestProperty(java.lang.String propertyName,
                           java.lang.String value)
```

Comment: So i need to have this cookie created which has the username and pwd and posted on the URL. The Jsession ID for the same cookie will be used for other Get and PUT request to different URL which uses the same session.

Comment: It doesn't matter what do you need this for. Your task is to understand what request your CURL command generates and then how to replicate it with Java. Or get the spec from your server-side and to understand what request and what params it expects. Either way, I still suggest that you use 3d party Http Client instead of coding your Http request on your own

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. This Worked. There is one last piece. Once I successfully post as above i need to use the same session and perform a get request on a different url. This time i do not use the user name and password JSON. how can i do it. or do i need to post a separate question for that??

Comment: Your first request returns a cookie that needs to be used as your session identifier, so you don't have to present credentials again. So, what you are asking is how to use a cookie to identify your current session against the server for which  you performed your authentication already. I don't know that answer to that, and yes, I suppose it warrants a separate question. BTW, just curious, what did you use to send your HTTP request? A third party library? if so which one. Also, if my answer helped you, please accept it as the right answer, and vote for it, so it may help others

Comment: you are correct i need a cookie to take forward the session. i used the your MgntUtils library  to get the post request working.i have accepted the answer but dont seem to be able to upvote it though.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, Thank you for accepting the answer. I guess that you can not up-vote it due to your low reputation. Once you pick up some points you will get the right to up-vote. I am glad you found my library useful.