# How do I take forward a session from a authenticator POST request into a GET request in JAVA?

Tags: java, session-cookies

please refer to this [Java equivalent of a curl cookie statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011809/java-equivalent-of-a-curl-cookie-statement/63012623?noredirect=1#comment111607622_63012623)

I have a Java code where a post request works perfectly as follows using MgntUtils library as mentioned in the above link.

here the code :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");

client.setConnectionUrl("http://egurl/app/app1/session/login");

client.sendHttpRequest(HttpMethod.POST, "{\"username\":\"acd\",\"password\":\"pwd\",\"isPasswordEncrypted\":\"false\"}");
```

i need to use the same session and use it to get some data from a different URL eg.  http://egurl/app/app1/param/paramgrp/1234

is there a way i can use session to get this done. i am fairly new to `GET` and `POST` in JAVA so need some help.

Thanks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using jsoup wrapper classes. please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie) link to have a better understanding.